# Is my solution to fixed timestep with delta time and interpolation wrong?

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml, timedelta, linear-interpolation

I am trying to write simple loop with **fixed delta time used for physics and interpolation** before rendering the state. I am using Gaffer on games tutorial on fixed timesteps and I tried to understand it and make it work.

```
float timeStep = 0.01;
float alpha = 1.0;
while (isOpen()) {
    processInput();
    deltaTime = clock.restart(); // get elapsed time
    if (deltaTime > 0.25) { deltaTime = 0.25; } // drop frame guard
    accumulator += deltaTime;
    while (accumulator >= timeStep) {
        // spritePosBefore = sprite.getPosition();
        accumulator -= timeStep;
        // sprite.move(velocity * timeStep, 0);
        // spritePosAfter = sprite.getPosition();
    }
    if (accumulator > timeStep) { alpha = accumulator / timeStep; } else { alpha = 1.0; }
    // sprite.setPosition(Vector2f(spritePosBefore * (1 - alpha) + spritePosAfter * alpha));
    clear();
    draw(sprite);
    display();
}
```

Now, everything looks good. I have fixed timestep for physics, draw whenever I can after physics are updated and interpolate between two positions. It should work flawless but I can still see sprite stuttering or even going back by one pixel once in a while. Why does it happen? Is there any problem with my code? I spent last two days trying to understand game loop which would ensure me flawless motions but it seems like it doesn't work as I thought it will. Any idea what could be improved?

Comment: [Gaffer on Games - Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the if statement and always calculate alpha; the if statement will never be executed as the condition is always false after the while loop is exited!

After the loop the accumulator will be between 0 and timeStep so you just end up drawing the latest position instead of interpolating.

Comment: Yeah, I found this out like three days ago and deleted this statement ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you do it is necessarily wrong but it looks a bit overcomplicated. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do so I'm just going to share the way I implement a "fixed time step" in my SFML applications.
The following is the simplest way and will be "good enough" for most applications. It's not the most precise though (the can be a little error between the measured time and the real time) :

```
    sf::Clock clock;    
    sf::Event event;
    while (window_.isOpen()) {
        while (window_.pollEvent(event)) {}

        if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > FLT_FIXED_TIME_STEP) {
            clock.restart();
            update(FLT_FIXED_TIME_STEP);
        }

        render();
    }
```

And if you **really** need precision, you can add a float variable that will act as a "buffer" :

```
    sf::Clock clock;    
    sf::Event event;
    float timeBeforeNextStep = 0.f; // "buffer"
    float timeDilation = 1.f; // Useful if you want to slow or speed up time ( <1 for slowmo, >1 for speedup)
    while (window_.isOpen()) {
        while (window_.pollEvent(event)) {}

        timeBeforeNextStep -= clock.restart().asSeconds() * timeDilation;
        if (timeBeforeNextStep < FLT_FIXED_TIME_STEP) {
            timeBeforeNextStep += FLT_FIXED_TIME_STEP; // '+=', not '=' to make sure we don't lose any time.
            update(FLT_FIXED_TIME_STEP);

            // Rendering every time you update is not always the best solution, especially if you have a very small time step.
            render();
        }
    }
```

You might want to use another buffer for rendering (if you want to run at exactly 60 FPS for example).

Comment: In first example I don't think it's good way to implement loop with fixed time step. For example if time step is let's say 1/60 second and time between frames is 0.25 second, you are updating your physics using fixed value where you get 1/60 s of time in game for 0.25 s in real life.  Second version seems about right but even if timeBeforeNextStep is less than fixed time step, you could still use this remaining value to interpolate before drawing. This is something what I am trying to achieve but I am not sure if my implementation is correct as I still feel that movement is a bit sluggish.

Comment: @Advent Ok, now I see what you're trying to do, I didn't understand the first time :). What you need to do is set your sprite position to ```posA + ((posB - posA) / distanceAB) * timeSinceLastStep``` where "timeSinceLastStep is the  time elapsed since your sprite was at posA. I've never done this but that's how I would do it. Good luck !